# 620: Too many queries using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API V3 to reverse-geocode a lot of locations (~100) on a page. After about 10 or so, I start getting a 620 error: too many queries.

What's a good way to delay the requests and ensure that they all get completed given that they're asynchronous?

EDIT:
Here's what I have so far. It completes all the requests most of the time, but it doesn't retry failed requests.

```
function replaceAddresses() {
    var delay = 0;
    $(".lat-lon-address").each(function(index) {
        window.setTimeout(queryGeocoder, delay, this);          
        delay += 1000;
    });
}

function queryGeocoder(elem) {
    geocoder.getLocations(new GLatLng(
        elem.getAttribute("lat"),
       elem.getAttribute("lon")), 
        function(response) {
            handleAddress(response, elem);
        }); 
}

function handleAddress(response, elem) {
    if (!response || response.Status.code != 200) {
        console.log("status code: " + response.Status.code)
    } else {
        place = response.Placemark[0];
        point = new GLatLng(place.Point.coordinates[1],
                        place.Point.coordinates[0]);

        elem.innerHTML = place.address;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Comment: Not sure if its applicable, but I recommend caching the results so you don't have to hit Google so often

Comment: @jarrett: Caching is not that practical with reverse geocoding. It's much more feasible with normal geocoding (address to coordinates).

Comment: I'd suggest showing the code for `queryGeocoder()` so we can see what you do for success vs. failure, otherwise I don't think you're going to be able to get the help you need.

Comment: originally I thought it would complicate the post unnecessarily, but I think you're right-- added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Last time I checked you are only allowed 2500 geocoding requests per day (based on your ip). This should be enough for you but you may need to purchase a larger limit if you use larger data sets.

**Tips**

Store your geocoded information locally, perhaps in a database. Fetch the values from the database instead of using Google's web service. It'll be much faster this way also. If a location is missing geographical information only then should you geocode it.

When you write some new code which uses geocoding don't test it with all 600 addresses, first try one or 2 addresses to make sure you don't needlessly blow through half your daily allowance with some dysfunctional code.

Do the geocoding client side if you can, this won't count towards your limit.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting 620, you probably need to throttle or reduce the number of requests.

Does your implementation comply with the terms of service? I don't see any code that displays these results on a map (as per ToS).